# MySQL grant create databases and select on specific databases

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have all these mysql databases:

[image]

I need to create a user able to

1. Create new databases
2. Select on all databases tables, **except `test01` database**

By doing this:

```
CREATE USER 'bduser000'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY 'User000pass';

GRANT SELECT ON airplanecrashes.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
GRANT SELECT ON airports.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
GRANT SELECT ON craftbeer.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
... (except test01)
```

.. bduser000 is not able to create new databases but is able to select tables in specific databases.

By doing this:

```
CREATE USER 'bduser000'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY 'User000pass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'bduser000'@'%%'
```

.. bduser000 is able to create new databases, but it is also able to select over `test01` database

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way. But it fits my need because I need to create only one new database:

```
CREATE USER 'bduser000'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY 'User000pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newDatabaseName.* TO 'bduser000'@'%%'

GRANT SELECT ON airplanecrashes.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
GRANT SELECT ON airports.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
GRANT SELECT ON craftbeer.* to 'bduser000'@'%%'
... (except test01)
```

Note that the first grant is over a database which do not exist yet: `newDatabaseName`.